# Partition full on Ubuntu, I have to move a mount point but I don't know how

Tags: ubuntu

I have a server with a full partition. If I type

```
root@server:/dev# df -H
Filesystem                             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                                   4.2G     0  4.2G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                  838M  9.5M  828M   2% /run
/dev/mapper/TV--INSTORE--vg-root       13G   12G  112M 100% /
tmpfs                                  4.2G     0  4.2G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                  5.3M     0  5.3M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                  4.2G     0  4.2G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                              247M  106M  129M  46% /boot
/dev/sdb1                              527G  4.7G  495G   1% /data
cgmfs                                  103k     0  103k   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
overlay                                527G  4.7G  495G   1% /data/docker/overlay2/7769c388ccc9c8a14a08e12932b05a8c384144bead64c74e61950914c590de5a/merged
overlay                                527G  4.7G  495G   1% /data/docker/overlay2/0eca01cbad8077e00d6411b7eb079017290b49619ac4a260ae4fd7cbd3f45701/merged
overlay                                527G  4.7G  495G   1% /data/docker/overlay2/a70cd62c5ff52498f3f767cac7eff4eb82b61f4f96bac83ac48438c2d76ac3d0/merged
shm                                     68M     0   68M   0% /data/docker/containers/483b952cd54b067330cbd52e1fee25b2f77aed0f0e8364cdaaaccdd1629628e4/shm
shm                                     68M     0   68M   0% /data/docker/containers/7acf87a8175389b1bf012cf1b93d5222a9b6fc201d77c97b4507220af4dca4a2/shm
shm                                     68M     0   68M   0% /data/docker/containers/8ac4d5448661b085b69c9e7f814bb5822ec6be09d15f2bb06fc086ea4224cf8c/shm
tmpfs                                  838M     0  838M   0% /run/user/1000
```

It's not a server I manage, I'm a developer, but I need to fix this asap.
I notice that I have a lot of space on `/dev/sdb1`

Now if I type

```
du -sh /* | sort -h
0   /dev
0   /initrd.img
0   /initrd.img.old
0   /proc
0   /sys
0   /vmlinuz
0   /vmlinuz.old
4.0K    /lib64
4.0K    /srv
8.0K    /media
8.0K    /mnt
16K /lost+found
24K /tmp
56K /root
60K /home
6.7M    /etc
9.0M    /run
13M /bin
14M /sbin
99M /boot
625M    /lib
851M    /var
1.3G    /usr
4.3G    /data
8.0G    /opt
```

Basically now every data on my server is in `/opt` that is mounted on the disk with 13 GB. I understand that I need to move `/opt/` to `/dev/sda1` where I have a lot of GB it's right? How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create new folder on /dev/sdb1

> mkdir /data/opt-backup

2. Copy all the data to opt-backup folder

> cd /opt
>
> mv ./* /data/opt-backup

Comment: you also can mount via bind after. moving your data the /opt to /data/opt like `mount -o bind /opt /data/mnt`